# Associate AWS WAFv2 web acl to ApiGatewayV2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-waf, terraform0.12+

I want to associate a WAFv2 Web ACL to an API GatewayV2 HTTP stage.

Following the terraform [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/wafv2_web_acl_association), I tried this:

```
resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl_association" "this" {
  resource_arn = aws_apigatewayv2_stage.this.arn
  web_acl_arn  = aws_wafv2_web_acl.this.arn
}
```

However, this was not accepted, with the error being:

> Error: WAFInvalidParameterException: Error reason: The ARN isn’t valid. A valid ARN begins with arn: and includes other information separated by colons or slashes., field: RESOURCE_ARN, parameter: arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-2::/apis/abcd1234/stages/my-stage

From the AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_AssociateWebACL.html), the pattern for the ARN is:

```
arn:aws:apigateway:region::/restapis/api-id/stages/stage-name
```

However, only the ARNs of the old API Gateway uses "**restapis**" in its ARN. The v2 gateways uses just "**apis**.

1. Is this why the ARN is invalid?
2. How can I associate a AWS API GatewayV2 HTTP Stage to an AWS WAFv2 Web ACL?

As requested, here is code for a gateway:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "this" {
  name          = "example-http-api"
  protocol_type = "HTTP"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "this" {
  filename      = "example.zip"
  function_name = "Example"
  role          = var.lambda_arn
  handler       = "index.handler"
  runtime       = "nodejs10.x"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "get" {
  api_id             = aws_apigatewayv2_api.this.id
  integration_type   = "AWS_PROXY"
  integration_method = "GET"
  integration_uri    = aws_lambda_function.this.invoke_arn
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "get" {
  api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api.this.id
  route_key = "$default"
  target    = "path/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.get.id}"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_stage" "this" {
  api_id = aws_apigatewayv2_api.this.id
  name   = "example-stage"
}
```

And code for a Web-ACL:

```
 resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "this" {
  scope       = "REGIONAL"

  default_action {
    allow {}
  }

  rule {
    name     = "common-rule-set"
    priority = 1

    override_action {
      none {}
    }

    statement {
      managed_rule_group_statement {
        name        = "AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet"
        vendor_name = "AWS"
      }
    }

    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = false
      metric_name                = "common-rule-set"
      sampled_requests_enabled   = false
    }
  }
  
  visibility_config {
    cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = false
    metric_name                = "web-acl"
    sampled_requests_enabled   = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code used for WAF and API Gateway and not only association part?

Comment: I have done so now @MarkoE

Comment: @Mathias Lykkegaard Lorenzen, the blog post you linked was posted two years before the question. Nothing changed regarding WAF support for API Gateway V2.

Answer (score 15):

HTTP API doesn't have WAF support:

> The API V1 namespace represents REST APIs and API V2 represents
> WebSocket APIs and the new HTTP APIs.
> Source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-http-apis-for-amazon-api-gateway/

And

> Currently, we do not support WAF for HTTP APIs. We have a backlog item
> for this request. Thank you for reaching out.
> https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=942361

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a mistake in your code. For the API Gateway stage, you are using this block:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_stage" "example" {
  api_id = aws_apigatewayv2_api.this.id
  name   = "example-stage"
}
```

while in the WAF association you are using:

```
resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl_association" "this" {
  resource_arn = aws_apigatewayv2_stage.this.arn
  web_acl_arn  = aws_wafv2_web_acl.this.arn
}
```

Change the `resource_arn = aws_apigatewayv2_stage.this.arn` to `resource_arn = aws_apigatewayv2_stage.example.arn`. You named the API Gateway stage resource `example` but you were trying to access attributes of a resource named `this`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, I was quickly making some changes since you wanted more code. The error I get is not due to a terraform source code error (I'll correct the terraform in the question), but as specified, that the ARN is invalid (WAFInvalidParameterException).